# How to select new element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

why my alert does not work?

```
$('.checkprice').click(function(el){      
    $(this).addClass('checkcheck');
});

$( '.checkcheck' ).on( "click", function() {
   alert('yes');
});
```

May be .checkcheck creates more longer, than .on() start?

Waht I must to do?

Comment: Use delegation: `$(document).on("click", ".checkcheck", function () {/*...*/});`

Comment: May be idiot, but why don't you create the listener on the .cheprices?

Comment: (Misclicking and mobile version won't let me edit)you can do this on your .checkprice listener `$(this).on("click.checkcheck",function(){alert('yes')});`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will setup event handlers immediately on all matched elements. For instance, the following code will apply to any element that has `.checkcheck` as a class only at the time the code is ran, and not at some future time:

```
$( ".checkcheck" ).on( "click", handleCheck );
```

If that class is added to an element at a future time, this handler *will not* handle click events for it, since it didn't have the class at the time `$.fn.on` was called originally.

The most popular way around this issue is to leverage *Event Delegation*, which utilizes the bubbling-nature of JavaScript events. Rather than placing a handler directly on all `.checkcheck` elements, we can place one further up the DOM tree:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".checkcheck", handleCheck );
```

Now we don't care if an element has `.checkcheck` as a class when this script is ran, we only care if it has that class when the event bubbles up to the document. This means we can add brand new elements to the DOM, given them the `.checkcheck` class, and they will trigger `handleCheck` when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

As Robin mentioned, try something similar to

```
var checked = false;
$('.checkprice').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('checkcheck');
    $(this).click(function(){
        if ( checked == false ) {
            alert('yes');
            checked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

I was also unaware of the `one()` event which is fancy, and rids the need for checking a variable and firing off multiple redundant events.

```
$('.checkprice').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('checkcheck');
    $(this).one('click', function(){
        alert('yes');
    });
});
```

If you need the check to only fire once then `one()` could be used on both events.

```
$('.checkprice').one('click.checkprice', function(){
    $(this).addClass('checkcheck');
    $(this).one('click', function(){
        alert('yes');
    });
});
```

You can also use `on()` delegation on the body as Jonathan mentioned

```
var checked = false;
$('body').on('click', '.checkprice', function(){
    $(this).addClass('checkcheck');
});

$('body').on('click', '.checkcheck', function() {
   alert('yes'); 
   checked = true;
});
```

Comment: That would add a new click handler every time you clicked it. First click would add a class, second click would alert once, third click would alert twice, etc. etc. Things could get out of handle fairly quickly :)

Comment: That's actually correct, thanks for pointing that out. Added a fix.

Comment: You could use [`$.fn.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which will immediately remove itself after execution.

Comment: Well ain't that snazzy. Thanks again.

Comment: I actually just realized that fiddling on my own and updated. Thanks again man. I'm still learning a lot. Coming in handy for sure.

Comment: My pleasure. jQuery is a fantastic library that has a lot of esoteric secrets to be learned. Once you start to really get involved with it, it can consume you (in a good way) ;)